# LINQ grouping and counting

Tags: c#, linq

I know this question is similar to a previous one of mine but I can't figure this out.

data:

```
dept  needOn    status
foo   5/1/2011  closed
foo   5/1/2011  closed
foo   5/1/2011  closed
foo   5/1/2011  closed
foo   5/1/2011  open
foo   5/1/2011  open
```

looking for this output:

```
dept  needOn    status   count
foo   5/1/2011  closed   4
foo   5/1/2011  open     2
```

I thought this would work:

```
var query3 = from q3 in query2
             group new { q3.Status }
                by new { q3.Dept, q3.NeedOnWeek, q3.Status } into g
             select new
             {
                 dept = g.Key.Dept,
                 needOnWeek = g.Key.NeedOnWeek,
                 status = g.Key.Status,
                 count = g.Count(x => x.Status)
             };
```

Both errors apply to: `count = g.Count(x => x.Status)`

Error   1   Cannot convert lambda expression to delegate type 'System.Func' because some of the return types in the block are not implicitly convertible to the delegate return type

Error   2   Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'bool'

Thanks for your patience and help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var query3 = from q3 in query2
             group q3
                by new { q3.Dept, q3.NeedOnWeek, q3.Status } into g
             select new
             {
                 dept = g.Key.Dept,
                 needOnWeek = g.Key.NeedOnWeek,
                 status = g.Key.Status,
                 count = g.Count()
             };
```